# Jest: whats the diff between jest.fn() and jest.fn().mockImplementation()

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

```
jest.fn(() => 'something')
jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'something')
```

Is there any difference between these?  bit confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference. [From the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn):

> `mockFn.mockImplementation(fn)`
>
> Accepts a function that should be used as the implementation of the mock. The mock itself will still record all calls that go into and instances that come from itself – the only difference is that the implementation will also be executed when the mock is called.
>
> Note: `jest.fn(implementation)` is a shorthand for `jest.fn().mockImplementation(implementation)`.